# Ajax call inside a while loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, while-loop, get

I want Ajax to get information while the information is valid. So if I do

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var url = '/my/url/';
            var ses = true;
            var i = 0;
            while (ses) {
                i++;
                var temp;
                $.get(url + "?get=" + i, function (data) {
                    if (data != '') {
                        temp = data;
                        sortArticles(data);
                    }
                });
                if(temp == '') ses = false;
            }
        });
```

If I do this without `while` (putting 0 instead of `get` var), I get the information I need, but if I put it like this, I enter an infinite loop and the page breaks. By the way, I tested and the `if(data != '')` statement works as intended.

I don't know why `temp` doesn't change the state of the `ses` variable. I tried putting an else statement inside `$.get(..)`

```
else ses = false;
```

but it doesn't do the trick neither.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: An AJAX call in a while loop isn't a great idea. Is there no way to find out exactly how many requests you need to make before you start to loop? Or, better still, change your server implementation to return all the required data in a single request.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm using ASP.NET MVC, so the problem is, if I return all of the results (they're JSON) I just get a result as `System.Web.AjaxRequest`, or something similar, as a single plain string, not the actual array of JSON strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery ajax (as most ajax implementations), which `$.get()` is a shorthand for, is asynchronouos be default. The callback function is only executed once the request is complete. The while continues indefinitely since without yielding control out to the JS engine the callback doesn't get a chance to do it's work - even if the request(s) are done.

In order to continuously send requests, try like this:

```
function requestMore(i) {
  $.get('/my/url/?get=' + i, function (data) {
     if (data != '') {
       sortArticles(data);
       requestMore(i + 1);
     }
  });
}

(document).ready(function () {
  requestMore(1);
});
```

Comment: Recursion, never would've thought of it. But then again, I didn't know it was anync until I read your answer. Thank you very much! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote your code `temp` will never be `''`.
The problem is `temp` is not a string. It's undefined.

Instead of:

```
if(temp == '') ses = false;
```

write:

```
if(typeof(temp) == 'undefined') ses = false;
```

Comment: Problem with that one is, it only returns me the first result, not the other ones.

Comment: Of course when you set while(ses), and ses becomes false.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var url = '/my/url/';
            var ses = true;
            var i = 0;
            while (ses) {
                i++;
                var temp='';
                $.get(url + "?get=" + i, function (data) {
                    if (data != '') {
                        temp = data;
                        sortArticles(data);
                    }
                });
                if(temp == '') ses = false;
            }
        });
```

This will work.Initialize temp as a blank string as shown :)